# Django paginate ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am beginner to Django. Currently, I can do pagination like this.

```
class CarView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    paginate_by = 10
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
```

For another view, I need to filter also and I do like this.

```
class DialogueView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = DialogueSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        paginate_by = 2
        user = self.request.user
        return Dialogue.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

But, it doesn't paginate anymore. How shall I do? Do I need to use APIView? If so, could you please guide me?

Comment: Why have you put the `paginate_by` into `get_queryset`, rather than at module level?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more by code?

Comment: I don't see what code is needed. In the first class you have `paginate_by` in the right place; in the second, you've put it in the wrong place, inside the method.

Comment: Oh true. Thanks for your help.